# Grails Spring Security @Secured not working

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I have been able to implement the @Secured annotation in one controller of my application. Yet, @Secured('ROLE_ADMIN') will NOT work anywhere else within the project.

It will only specifically work anywhere within my program controller and no where else.

For example, if I use it as so;

```
@Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
```

The IDE gives me;
Multiple markers at this line
    - Groovy:class Secured is not an annotation in @Secured
    - Groovy:unable to resolve class Secured , unable to find class for

I have even tried checking the Spring Security Config file to check if annotations were set correctly (which seemingly they were).
Any ideas? Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem.  The below solution did not help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are probably missing the required import.

At the top of each controller where you need the annotations use the grails import for Secured. Then you can use the annotations for the class or method as needed.

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

//import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured; - this is in older version, 
//                                                grails 2.0 and older

@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_SUPERVISOR'])
class myClass {

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not work for me.  It does not find grails.plugins.springsecurity.  Im using spring-security-core:2.0-RC2

Comment: There had been a change in spring security plugin, the annotation is now in package import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" )
```

And add annotation support in spring configuration:

```
    <!-- Allow configuration annotation (@Annotation-based configuration)-->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Enable scan classes -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.your.package" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Denis. It's still giving me the "-Groovy:unable to resolve class PreAuthorize, unable to find class for annotation" and "-Groovy:class PreAuthorize is not an annotation in @PreAuthorize" errors.

I have set "Annotation" in the spring security config file, yet it doesn't seem to recognize annotations outside of my programController(). Very weird.

Comment: Maybe you missed annotation configuration in spring context? I added this to answer

Comment: @Denis Loshkarev, where to place it? `applicationContext.xml`?